# How to populate Listview with async task in android fragment and should load on fragment launch

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, asynchronous

I am developing an android application using fragments and async task to populate listview data, The main problem is async task cant execute in the onCreateView() automatically when a fragment is called and also not able to save instance state when i switch between fragments

Comment: Could you please be more clear about your exact requirement and problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been able to solve the problem, it was in my asyncTask onPreExecute() i had refreshMenuItem which was causing the main problem so i solved it using ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute() class

Answer (score 1):

Try to use   onActivityCreated() method in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Service to the loading, using the LocalBroadcastManager to message the fragment when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

Diddy

as Chandra said try to execute your AsynTask in OnActivityCreated() method.
and when data load to dataObject then populate it into listview adapter as below.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
             new AsyncGetData().execute();
}


class AsynGetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // Add data into dataObject from web-services or database into ArrayList or String[] and use this dataObject in OnPostExecute() method below

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), dataObject));

            }

}
```